# Use of "disabled" attribute has been deprecated, please use "disable"

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ui.bootstrap

I have been getting a warning since I upgraded angularjs the other day. It happens any time I open a ui.bootstrap modal.

Here is the warning I get in chrome-beta 44:

```
angular.js:11655 Use of "disabled" attribute has been deprecated, please use "disable"
```

Is this something that has been happening with the latest release of angular? Should I spend any more time determining what is going on? I have spent several hours this week looking at different reasons and I am just wondering if other users are experiencing this and what (if anything) they have been doing about it?

**JS Includes**

- jQuery v2.1.3
- angularJS v1.3.15
- angular-ui-bootstrap v0.13.0
- bootstrap v3.3.1 *is also loading if that matters due to external loading*
- angular-file-upload v1.1.5 [github](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

**What have I tried?**

- I tried looking at where angular is throwing this warning. It is pretty well obfuscated and doesn't yield me any useful information as it doesn't provide a stack trace.
- I have check my view html and checked on angularjs.org about ng-disabled. I did not see any changes, or maybe I missed something/looked in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In writing up this question and going back through what I have done, I discovered my issue.

The warning was being generated by the following directive in my modals view

```
<tab heading="Upload" disabled="report.RELEASE !== environment">
```

Changing this to the following fixed the issue

```
<tab heading="Upload" disable="report.RELEASE !== environment">
```

> disable (Defaults: false) : Whether tab is clickable and can be activated. Note that this was previously the disabled attribute, which is now deprecated.

The change is documented [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs/docs).